# How do I show progress on rsync without --progress similar to dd SIGUSR1

Tags: rsync

How do I show progress on rsync without `--progress` similar to sending `SIGUSR1` to `dd`?

When I accidentally start rsync without parameters on a large file and I neither pass `--progress` or `--partial`. Is there a way to show progress without restarting the whole file transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Send `SIGVTALRM` to the rsync process.

```
killall -VTALRM rsync
```

Comment: Or `SIGINFO` on BSDs (Ctrl+T).